# What are those robots from?

Tags: object-identification

I found these toys but not sure from where they are from. My guess would be something from Gundam but I'm not sure:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Found the first one [**Zock**](http://www.1999.co.jp/eng/10005552) from Gundam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first (with thanks to Juan Carlos Oropeza) is [MSM-10 Zock](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/MSM-10_Zock):

[image: Zock]

The second is [YMS-15 Gyan](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/YMS-15_Gyan):

[image: Gyan]

Both from the Mobile Suit Gundam series.